# DLL Project and GUI Project - Caliburn Micro: Model / View VM Questions

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am certain this question should bhave been asked before, but I am unable to find exactly what I am looking for;

Consider the following:

```
- Solution
-- Class Library Project [Caliburn.Micro] Referenced
--- [Models] Folder
---- LogEntryModel.cs
--- [ViewModels] Folder
---- LogEntryViewModel.cs
---- ShellViewModel.cs
-- WPF GUI Project [Caliburn.Micro] Referenced
--- [Views] Folder
---- LogEntryView.xaml
---- ShellView.xaml
```

so, I have 2 projects, one with Models and one with ViewModels and Views; 
This is my Bootstrapper:

```
    public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private CompositionContainer container;

        public AppBootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            this.container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     By default, we are configured to use MEF
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Configure()
        {



            var config = new TypeMappingConfiguration
            {
                DefaultSubNamespaceForViews = "WPFGUI.Views",
                DefaultSubNamespaceForViewModels = "ClassLibrary.ViewModels"
            };
            ViewLocator.ConfigureTypeMappings(config);
            ViewModelLocator.ConfigureTypeMappings(config);

            var catalog =
                new AggregateCatalog(
                    AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>());

            this.container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            var batch = new CompositionBatch();

            batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
            batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
            batch.AddExportedValue(this.container);
            batch.AddExportedValue(catalog);

            this.container.Compose(batch);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this.container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
        {
            var contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
            var exports = this.container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

            if (exports.Any())
            {
                return exports.First();
            }

            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var startupTasks =
                GetAllInstances(typeof(StartupTask))
                .Cast<ExportedDelegate>()
                .Select(exportedDelegate => (StartupTask)exportedDelegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(StartupTask)));

            startupTasks.Apply(s => s());

            DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
        }

    }
```

Now, when I try to use LogEntryModel bound to a listbox, I reveice `Cannot find view for ClassLibrary.Models.LogEntryModel.`

- I assume I need to 'tell' Caliburn to look for models in my Class Library project (how)
- Should I reference Caliburn.Micro in my Class Library? (Since it's a GUI thing?)
- Where should my ViewModels be, in the ClassLibrary or the GUI project?

---

[edit] 
I changed my Folder structure, my VM's and Models are now grouped together,
I updated bootstrapper.cs:

```
            var config = new TypeMappingConfiguration
            {
                DefaultSubNamespaceForViews = "WPFGUI.Views",
                DefaultSubNamespaceForViewModels = "ClassLibrary.ViewModels"
            };
            ViewLocator.ConfigureTypeMappings(config);
            ViewModelLocator.ConfigureTypeMappings(config);
```

The ShellViewModel still functions; but the LogEntryModel still displays:

```
Cannot find view for ClassLibrary.Models.LogEntryModel.
```

---

[edit 2]
LogEntryModel:

```
public class LogEntryModel
    {
        //GUID
        public Guid GUID { get; set; }
        //The log message string
        public string Message { get; set; }
        //The module that created the logentry (see enums Module for options)
        public int Module { get; set; }
        //The urgency (used for coloring: 0 = black (normal), 1 = red (error), 2 = cyan (info)
        public int Severity { get; set; }
        //User that triggered the logentry
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        //The datetime of the logentry
        public DateTime LogEntryDateTime { get; set; }

    }
```

LogEntryViewModel:

```
    public class LogEntryViewModel
    {
//This is for testing purposes only (I'd expect "Hello World" everywhere
        public String Message { get; set; } = "Hello World";
    }
```

LogEntryView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ServicesUI_WPF.Views.LogEntryView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFGUI.Views"
             DataContext="ClassLibrary.ViewModels.LogEntryViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="Red">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: LogEntryModel has nothing to do with view, its viewmodel wich calls view...so what is the name of view and viewmodel of Logentry.. the rule with caliburn is: LogentryView with LogViewModel.  so if its not the same rule, yes you have to indicate to caliburn.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the ViewModel also needs to exist? I think, as far as I was able to google, the issue is namespaces. But they all talk about separating VM from V and not M from VM and V, should I move my VM to my Model project and fix the issue that way?

Comment: i dont see your logic, see my answer and read the link. the rule exists for ViewModel and View and yes you could have VM and V in same library and Model in Other...i dont see viewmodels in your description... show more code... Shellviewmodel and logentryviewmodel

Comment: you should show your code shellviewmodel and logentryviewmodel, to avoid waste time

Comment: i suppose you have referenced in logentryview.xaml the library model?

Comment: erm, no.. I don't think so?

Comment: I added ```DataContext="ClassLibrary.ViewModels.LogEntryViewModel"``` to the UserControl, No change

Comment: show you complete logentryview.xaml..and i dont see how you call LogentryviewModel? from ShellviewModel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214607/discussion-between-fimlore-and-frenchy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working; after reviewing some Youtube links I noticed a pattern in things I was missing;

LogEntryModel:

```
namespace ServicesTools.Models
{
    public class LogEntryModel
    {
        //GUID
        public Guid GUID { get; set; }
        //The log message string
        public string Message { get; set; }
        //The module that created the logentry (see enums Module for options)
        public int Module { get; set; }
        //The urgency (used for coloring: 0 = black (normal), 1 = red (error), 2 = cyan (info)
        public int Severity { get; set; }
        //User that triggered the logentry
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        //The datetime of the logentry
        public DateTime LogEntryDateTime { get; set; }


    }
}
```

LogEntryViewModel

```
namespace ServicesTools.ViewModels
{
    public class LogEntryViewModel : Screen
    {
        //Create a property that will keep all data from LogEntryModel in this BindableCollecton
        private BindableCollection<LogEntryModel> _logEntries;
        public BindableCollection<LogEntryModel> LogEntries
        {
            get { return _logEntries; }
            set { _logEntries = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LogEntries);
            }
        }

        //On Instantiate; collect all the LogEntries from the datasource
        public LogEntryViewModel()
        {
            LogEntries = new BindableCollection<LogEntryModel>(GlobalConfig.Connection.GetLogEntries());
        }

    }
}
```

I have no LogEntryView, because that's being called in DebugView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ServicesTools.Views.DebugView" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ServicesTools.Views" 
             xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:ServicesTools.ViewModels;assembly=ServicesLibrary"
             xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls" xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
             xmlns:convert="clr-namespace:ServicesUI_WPF.Converters"
             >
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Border Padding="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource CompanyCore1SolidBrush}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{Binding Severity, Converter={StaticResource SeverityToColorConverter}}" >
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Consolas">
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}[{0:dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss}] {1}({2}), {3}">
                                                    <Binding Path="LogEntryDateTime"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Module" Converter="{StaticResource ModuleToEnumConverter}" />
                                                    <Binding Path="Module" />
                                                    <Binding Path="Message" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I almost had it working in the ListBox, but I was missing "DisplayMemberPath" initialy;
What I was also missing in the LogEntryViewModel was actual code that created (and filled) the property `BindableCollection<LogEntries>`, there was actually nothing to bind to.

The final thing I had to edit was the DebugViewModel:

```
namespace ServicesTools.ViewModels
{
    public class DebugViewModel : Screen
    {

        //Create an ObservableCollection property that will keep all LogEntries
        private ObservableCollection<LogEntryModel> _logEntries;
        public ObservableCollection<LogEntryModel> LogEntries
        {
            get { return _logEntries; }
            set 
            { 
              _logEntries = value;
              NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LogEntries) ;
            }
        }

        //On Instantiate; call GetLogEntries
        public DebugViewModel()
        {
            GetLogEntries();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call a stored procedure to reset TrackAndTrace
        /// Log an entry into the database with severity High on click
        /// Log an entry into the database with severity Debug on finish
        /// Refresh LogEntries
        /// </summary>
        public void TrackAndTraceReset()
        {
            //Log an Entry into the table
            HelperFunctions.CreateLogEntry(logEntryMessage:$"User Clicked the Track & Trace reset button", Enums.Severity.High, Enums.Module.Debug);

            //TODO something [...]

            HelperFunctions.CreateLogEntry(logEntryMessage: $"And it Worked!", Enums.Severity.Debug, Enums.Module.Debug);

            //Refresh the list of LogEntries
            GetLogEntries();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clear the current property LogEntries (if not Null), 
        /// then instantiate a new LogEntryViewModel and insert LogEntryViewModel.LogEntries property into LogEntries
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>ObservableCollection<LogEntryModel></returns>
        private ObservableCollection<LogEntryModel> GetLogEntries() {
            //If LogEntries is null, do nothing; otherwise Clear it
            LogEntries?.Clear();

            //Instantiate new LogEntryViewModel
            LogEntryViewModel _lEVM  = new LogEntryViewModel();

            //Insert Property into LogEntries property
            LogEntries = _lEVM.LogEntries;

            //TODO: if filter exists, filter the list

            return LogEntries;            
        }

    }
}
```

I am still testing with if I actually need to instantiate a new LogEntryViewModel() each time the log entries get updated, but that was the easiest way to update all entries in the list.

Answer (score 0):

if you desire to add new rules to link viewModel and view, you have to use [ViewLocator](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/custom-conventions):

some samples:

```
//link xxxxViewModel with xxxxViewX   
ViewLocator.NameTransformer.AddRule(@"ViewModel", @"ViewX");

//case when view and viewmodel are not in same library       
//link Cockpit.Core.Plugins.Plugins.Properties.xxxViewModel with
//Cockpit.General.Properties.Views.xxxView
ViewLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("Cockpit.Core.Plugins.Plugins.Properties", "Cockpit.General.Properties.Views");
```

Comment: I updated my question with some changes (Moved VM to ClassLibrary, to be with the Models) - The Views are now in a separate Assembly; I Changed the Bootstrapper.cs to reflect that (and the application was working as it was before).

The naming on all is the same, except for the namespace; however I can't find a way to connect Model with ViewModel with View in your link, only ViewModel with View?

Comment: yes, model are just data...so could you swhow how you call LogentryViewmodel? isuppose you have referenced the model library in the project where view and viewmodel are?

Comment: Updated my question